# Why aren't $.put() and $.delete() native in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We were having a discussion internally here at work about jQuery having built-in support for $.get() and $.post(), but not for $.put() and $.delete().

Some think that its to keep the js library size smaller. Others think that its not a feature that is often asked for, so is left to plugin developers to make.

What are some thoughts from the SO community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where do you stop? `$.options()`? `$.copy()`? `$.mkactivity()`?

There are too many potential HTTP verbs to bother to create a convenience method for each. Webapps haven't bothered too much with `PUT` and `DELETE` in the past, so they're not used that often. The gain from a convenience method is pretty small; there's not really any problem with just using `$.ajax()`.

Comment: "There are too many potential HTTP verbs to bother to create a convenience method for each." I can't imagine this thinking has ever been applied to anything concerning jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to pull a percentage out of my ass but I think 90-95% of front end devs will never need to use `$.delete` or `$.put`.

Comment: +1 though I think you're overestimating how many people would use them!

Comment: They become quite a bit more useful (and more common) when you're dealing with RESTful services, where `PUT` and `DELETE` have semantics and could be used to add or delete entries in a collection.